# How to list all datasets in CKAN (not only the active ones)

Tags: dataset, ckan

I am working on a project based on CKAN, and I am required to list in a page all the datasets that have the state "active" and "draft". When you go to the datasets page, you can only see the ones that have the state marked as "active", but not "draft". 
    If I use the API (call the `package_list()` method) or REST calls (`http://localhost/api/3/action/package_list`), CKAN only returns "active" datasets, but not "drafts". I double and triple checked the documentation, and apparently one cannot lists the datasets by their state. 
    Does anybody have a clue on how to do this? Has anybody done this already?
    Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If nothing else, you could [write an extension](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/extensions/tutorial.html) to do this.  The database call itself will be pretty simple:

```
SELECT id,title,name FROM package WHERE state='active' OR state='draft';
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to modify CKAN core to list the datasets that do not have the state "draft" or "deleted", and it works, but I do no want to touch CKAN's core, I want to do this using a plugin, so the normal thing to do is to implement `plugins.IActions` and override the `package_list` method with a custom one. I have already written my own extension to try to modify CKAN behavior on `method package_list()`, but I can't seem to figure it out how to make it work.
Here is my code:

```
@side_effect_free
def package_list_custom(context, data_dict=None):
    datasets = []
    dataset_q = (model.Session.query(model.Package)
     .join(model.PackageRole))
    for dataset in dataset_q:
        if dataset.state != 'draft' and dataset.state != 'deleted':
            datasets.append(dataset)
    return [dataset.id for dataset in datasets]

class Cnaf_WorkflowPlugin(plugins.SingletonPlugin):
    plugins.implements(plugins.IActions)

    def get_actions(self):
        return {
            'package_list' : package_list_custom
        }
```

If I modify CKAN core it works very well, but the problem is that I am not to touch it, so I am obliged to do it via an extension.

EDIT: Ok, I managed to make it work, you need to decorate the method with @side_effect_free. I modified my code, and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

The `package_search` API is capable of this, by searching for `state:draft` and setting the `include_drafts=True` flag. Something like this:

```
https://my-site.com/api/action/package_search?q=state:draft&include_drafts=True
```

You should be able to access this from a plugin with something like: `ckan.plugins.toolkit.get_action('package_search')(context=context, data_dict={'q': 'state:draft', 'include_drafts': True})` (you'll need to assemble the context yourself, containing a 'user' key for the current username and a 'userobj' key for the current user object).

Then make a page from the results.